# String cannot be cast to Integer session Attribute

Tags: java, session, authentication

Hello I am getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer

at this line of the code:

```
int est;
est=(Integer) session.getAttribute("estado");
```

I think that the problem is that "estado" is not filled yet. I use this session-attribubute in order to see if session has been signed in and so that it doesnt need to log in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `session.getAttribute("estado");` returns the session attribute held in `estado`, What happened here that, the JVM has found (during runtime) the returned value's type is `String` so when you tried to cast it into `Integer` it fired a `ClassCastException`

What you need here is to parse the result returned by the attribute `estado` using `Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("estado"));`, which was suggested in the answers

> NOTE: you maybe questioning that you have added an integer (not a `String`) to that attribute, but trace your code carefully considering that `request.getParameter("attrName")` returns a `String`, just an assumption

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** type-cast here, as `Integer` is not compatible with `String`.

Use [`Integer#parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to parse it as an `int`

```
est = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("estado"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use Integer.parseInt

```
int est= Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("estado").toString());
```